# Connecting signals with button handles

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, signals-slots

I am using Qt to create GUIs in python.

I created a QThread which has an infinite loop during which it emits some QtCore.SIGNAL in certain moments when certain conditions are fulfilled. In the main function I want to connect each signal with one button handler. I make in this fashion:

```
    self.workThread = WorkingThread()
    self.connect( self.workThread, QtCore.SIGNAL("button_right"), self.handle_a2_right)
    self.connect(self.workThread,QtCore.SIGNAL("button_left"), self.handle_a2_left)
    self.workThread.start()
```

where WorkingThread is my thread and handles are my button handles respectively. However when it achieves the first connection of signals the program gives the following error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnuradio/gr/top_block.py", line 151, in _coerce_endpoint
raise ValueError("unable to coerce endpoint")
ValueError: unable to coerce endpoint
```

Comment: This question seems to be off-topic, because the error is clearly raised by third-party code (i.e. [gnuradio](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki)).

Comment: It seems that this is not connected to Qt, but rather an error in gnuradio. Please ask new question.

Comment: This question seems to be off-topic, because the error is clearly raised by third-party code (i.e. gnuradio).

Answer (score 0):

The class you call connect on is a GNU Radio hierarchical block, not a QT GUI thing, as noted by jb and ekhumoro; most probably you want to do something like 
`self.qtgui_widget_instance.connect(SIGNAL...)`